# Simulation of CMYK color space based on icc profile

Tags: color-management

I am looking for the best solution for properly preparing printable graphics. At the moment I'm doing a screenshot in "Rendered" mode and then pasting graphics into Illustrator or Photoshop for checking preview. As we know Photoshop allows us to preview CMYK color space by pressing "Ctrl + Y". 
This is one solution but choosing the colors and lighting in blender we have to somehow guess which area of the graphics will be able to print faithfully and which is not.
It would be fantastic if blender could simulate the CMYK color space directly in viewport, I mean a mechanism similar to "False color" look used in Filmic color management.

Maybe You have any other suggestions?

Thx

[image]

Comment: No. I'd suggest render the image, then in Photoshop go to *Edit > Convert to Profile > e.g. IsoCoated v2 300* that's the usual way of converting to CMYK (tries its best to preserve the colors). Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50978/is-it-possible-to-save-cmyk-renders-from-blender

Comment: The conversion process itself is familiar to me, but I'm looking for a way to simulate cmyk color space directly in blender.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50978/is-it-possible-to-save-cmyk-renders-from-blender and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68574/colomanagement-workflow-how-to-achieve-requested-target-rgb-values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is understanding what *simulate* would mean. CMYK nor RGB are colour spaces per se, but rather colour encoding models.

This sort of a question would mean going through all of the nuances that may be in an ICC profile and simulating the resultant output on screen as though it were paper. This would be a dark labyrinth of colour primaries conversions from reference space to destination, illuminants, TACs, BPCs, etc.

Best advice is to learn Argyll and use that.